# Алгоритм бинарного поиска JAVA

Tags: java, массивы, алгоритм, поиск

Завел массив со значениями: `[15 17 21 33 33 33 59 66 77]`
Написал функцию, которая принимает массив, размер новой книги и возвращала бы количество больших по размеру.
Вызвал функцию, передав туда массив и размер новой книги, например 33.  Должно было получиться 3, получается 4.
Потом проверил 66, тоже получил неверный результат 7.

Прошу помощи!

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {15, 17, 21, 33, 33, 33, 59, 66, 77};
        int search = 33;
        int left = 0;
        int right = arr.length - 1;

        while (left < right) {
            int middle = (left + right) / 2;
            if (arr[middle] == search) {
                System.out.println(middle);
                break;
            } else if (arr[middle] > search) {
                right = middle - 1;
            } else if (arr[middle] < search) {
                left = middle + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что печатает ваш код? Индекс первого найденного (не обязательно первого по порядку) значения, совпадающего с  искомым. Если вам нужно `количество больших` по размеру, то это явно не то (по крайней мере, нужно от длины списка отнять этот самый индекс).

Кроме того, ваш код не способен вернуть индекс, если искомой величины в списке нет.

А для того, чтобы правильно обрабатывать дубликаты, код должен искать самое правое значение. Вот псевдокод из вики. Он так, как нужно, обрабатывает случаи дубликатов и отсутствия в списке

> Even if T is not in the array, n-R is the number of elements in the
> array that are greater than T

```
function binary_search_rightmost(A, n, T):
    L := 0
    R := n
    while L < R:
        m := floor((L + R) / 2)
        if A[m] > T:
            R := m
        else:
            L := m + 1
    return R - 1
```

На Java  ([онлайн пример](https://onlinegdb.com/BE1rD0XHO))

```java
int[] arr = {15, 17, 21, 33, 33, 33, 59, 66, 77};
int search = 33;

int L = 0;
int R = arr.length;

while (L < R) {
    int middle = (L + R) / 2;
    if (arr[middle] > search) {
        R = middle;
    } else  {
        L = middle + 1;
    }
}
System.out.println(arr.length - R);
//return arr.length - R;  если будете оформлять в виде функции
```

Comment: я так понимаю нужно функция, которая принимала бы этот массив размеров текущих книг, размер новой книги и вычисляла бы количество больших по размеру книг уже на полке. Требуемая алгоритмическая сложность: время O(log2n), дополнительная память O(1)

Comment: Да-да, именно это указанная функция и делает, если возвращать `n-R`

Comment: Я только начинаю и ":=" еще не проходил, мне надо попроще))

Comment: Это псевдокод, на джаве пишите по-джавийски - заготовка у вас ведь уже есть в вопросе, подправьте алгоритм только. Тело функции я на Java переписал, подправьте, если что не так, и заголовок функции сделайте.

Comment: Что-то ещё до сих пор непонятно?

Comment: Пытаюсь понять)))Не вызываем готовые реализации бинарного поиска?

Comment: Ну нет, цикл while - это своя реализация бинарного поиска, которая ищет самый правый подходящий элемент

Comment: https://github.com/netology-code/algo-homeworks/blob/master/tasks/Intro.md   "еслиинтересно"

Comment: Всё отлично подходит. Какие сомнения-то?

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение ответа от MBo, следует проверить значения в крайних точках отсортированного массива, что позволит сократить сложность проверки *в лучшем случае* (если значение `search` выходит за диапазон чисел в массиве) до константной O(1).

Пример реализации:

```java
public static int posFromRight(int search, int ... arr) {
    int left = 0;
    int right = arr.length;
    
    if (right > 0) {                             // массив не пустой?
        if (search < arr[left]) {                // проверить значение слева 
            right = 0;
        } else if (search >= arr[right - 1]) {   // проверить значение справа
            left = arr.length;
        }
    }
    
    while (left < right) {
        int mid = (left + right) / 2;
        if (arr[mid] > search) {
            right = mid;
        } else {
            left = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    return arr.length - right;
}
```

Тесты:

```java
int[] arr = {15, 17, 21, 33, 33, 33, 59, 66, 77};
int[] tests = {10, 15, 16, 17, 30, 33, 60, 66, 70, 77, 80};

for (int t : tests) {
    System.out.printf("%d -> %d%n", t, posFromRight(t, arr));
}
```

Результаты:

```
10 -> 9
15 -> 8
16 -> 8
17 -> 7
30 -> 6
33 -> 3
60 -> 2
66 -> 1
70 -> 1
77 -> 0
80 -> 0
```

Предыдущее [онлайн демо](https://ideone.com/QDaLLW)

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146527/discussion-on-answer-by-nowhere-man----java); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.